# Print a range of lines onto one line in awk

Tags: awk

I need to print a matched range of lines onto one line.

File contains:

```
banana
start
1
2
3
stop
banana
banana
start
5
6
stop
```

I need to output this as

```
start 1 2 3 stop
start 5 6 stop
```

I'm currently using basic `/start/,/stop/{print $0}` syntax to get my range, but 
I'm looking for a syntax with `awk` that will output my ranges on single lines.
(edited for clarity)

Comment: I gave this one minus since request is changed.  This made all answer to your request not valid.

Comment: I thought the original intent was implicit, given that I'm using match ranges, rather than clever search & replace logic with regex or something. Sorry for the "change".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
awk '/start/,/stop/{if($0 ~ /stop/){print}; if($0 !~ /stop/){printf $0" "}}' file
```

Comment: You do not need the semicolon `;`

Comment: You should always specify format for `printf` and change `printf $0 " "` to `printf "%s ",$0`.  If file does contain eks `%s` this will fail.

Comment: That's giving me:
    banana banana banana start (line break)
    1 2 3 banana banana start  (line break)
    4 5 6 banana...

In other words, it's ignoring my range, and just omitting the last line of my range.

Comment: @wolfmason, huh, where'd you get those bananas from

Comment: They fell off of the "unwanted info" tree into my file, thus I'm using a match range to ignore them.

Comment: @wolfmason, answer adjusted to suit your latest input

Comment: That's the one!  Thanks soooooo much!

Answer (score 1):

A `gnu awk` version (due to limit of RS on some awk)

```
awk '$1=$1 {print $0,RS}' RS="stop" file
```

---

a more robust version

```
awk '{$1=$1} $0 {print $0,RS}' RS="stop" file
```

---

this should work on all `awk` version

```
awk '/stop/ {print;next} {printf "%s ",$0}' file
```

---

a banana version

```
awk '/start/ {f=1} f {s=s?s" "$0:$0} /stop/ {print s;f=s=0}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ORS = $1 == "stop" ? "\n" : " "; print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk '$1 ~ /^start$/{in_range = 1; ORS = " ";} $1 ~ /^stop/{in_range = 0; ORS = "\n"; print $0; next;} in_range{print $0}' test2.txt
```